# How to report viral hoax blogs on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The abuse page http://wordpress.com/abuse/ has no options for viral hoax entries, such as https://wausaunews.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/big-hospital-finally-telling-the-truth-about-cancer-johns-hopkins/

Edit: [Snopes has reported this as a hoax](http://www.snopes.com/medical/disease/cancerupdate.asp).

The options for reporting abuse are the following:

- This content is spam
- This content should be marked as mature
- This content is abusive
- This content promotes self-harm/suicide
- This content infringes upon my copyright

None seems to cover viral hoax, which seems very abusive because it promotes disinformation and farms clicks on ads.

Comment: I am shocked - _shocked!_ - to see a site that is less-than-truthful on the internet. Honestly, this isn't abuse. If someone left the content of this site in a brochure on your windshield would you report it to the police? That said, you might be able to justify reporting it as spam, because a number of those ads appear to violate the wordpress.com TOS.

Comment: @AlE. I disagree that it's not abuse. This "hoax" has appeared in many blogs over time. It eventually gets removed, but before it does, thousands of people re-post it on Facebook and then visit the blog and leave comments (for or against). The blogger doesn't put it on his page for information, but rather for traffic. See my edit for how it's a scam.

Comment: @pnuts WordPress defines abuse on http://en.wordpress.com/complaints/ as `Defamation, abuse, threats: We suspend content for inciting violence or threatening or impersonating a private person.` So, in the sense that this report claims to represent Johns Hopkins hospital, it might indeed be impersonation.

Comment: @pnuts Right now, WP's abuse page is not working for me regardless of the form of abuse I specify.

Answer (score 0):

I reported it as "this content is abusive" per the "Responsibility of Contributors" section of the WordPress [Terms of Service](http://en.wordpress.com/tos/):

- the Content is not spam, is not machine- or randomly-generated, and **does not contain unethical or unwanted commercial content designed to** drive traffic to third party sites or boost the search engine rankings of third party sites, or to further unlawful acts (such as phishing) or **mislead recipients as to the source of the material** (such as spoofing);

(emphasis mine)